# MongoDB compass unable to [Select Type] select specific type

Tags: complex-data-types

in Insert Document, e.g if I want to select "Object" type, i am unable to find it, unable to scroll from up/down arrow keys

1   _id : objectId("5ecgftr654gfhfyr7565gfvy5ff")                                      ObjectId
2   Address : " "                                                                      String